# Excel: Data across multiple columns and rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, cells, countif

Currently have a table like this:

[image: Timesheet]

How can I consolidate and count the hours per person spent on each day. Need to be on seperate lines due to working on different tasks but want to bring in all together for reporting purposes.

I'm stuck!

Comment: "I'm stuck!". Ok, but where are you stuck? What did you already try? Did that include pivot tables (and their sum off capability) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, lay out your spreadsheet this way.

Then in cell B2 type @sum(B3:b4).  repeat that for each day and each employee heading.  (b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, b5, c5, d5, e5, f5, b8, c8, d8, e8, f8 )

Now click on the DATA tab. Highlight your entire data.  Click the arrow under Group option in the ribbon bar.  Chose Auto Outline.

Your data should now look like this.

You can report however you like on the main heading for each employee by clicking on the minus sign to the left of the row numbers.

You can also do PivotTables.  I am not familiar with those.